# Is the modulation on my WiFi different to the modulation on cellular?

Tags: modulation

Is the modulation method, or nature of modulation otherwise, between my phone and my WiFi modem, versus my phone and a cellular mast, different?

Comment: Yes. Modulation even changes for different WIFI protocols and connection speeds.

Comment: yes. Wikipedia-level research could have answered that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From google:
3G-5G appears to use OFDM —along with QPSK og QAM depending on channel conditions.

WiFi 802.11b used some CDMA-dialect, 802.11a and g uses OFDM along with BPSK, QPSK or QAM.

WiFi mainly use frequencies around 2.4Ghz, while cellphones have used lower frequencies around 900Mhz (due to larger distances). Both have recently added capability for using higher frequencies.

Comment: 3G is typically a specific kind of DSSS-CDMA. But things are still pretty different – due to the very different problems encountered by the respective channels.